# Gimp options on Unity panel greyed out unless sudo

Tags: 13.10, permissions, gimp

I'm using Gimp2.8-2.9 on 13.10 and all of the drop-down options to modify a photo from the unity panel menu are greyed out unless gimp is run as sudo. I can only assume this is a permission issue. 
Gimp shouldn't have to be run with sudo.

**UPDATE**

Right-clicking on the photo has the same options available I just cannot use the drop-down menu items from the unity panel for some reason.

`mchid@mchid:~$ ls -l .gimp-2.8
total 824
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 brushes
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid    739 May 23 08:29 colorrc
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid   1863 May 23 08:29 controllerrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 curves
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid     57 May 23 08:29 dockrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 dynamics
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 environ
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 fractalexplorer
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 gfig
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 gflare
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 gimpressionist
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 gradients
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid    430 May 23 08:28 gtkrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 interpreters
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid   2597 May 23 08:28 lastval_descriptions.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 levels
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid  99367 May 23 08:29 menurc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 modules
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 palettes
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid    102 May 23 08:29 parasiterc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 patterns
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid 541388 May 23 08:28 pluginrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 plug-ins
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 scripts
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid   2493 May 23 08:29 sessionrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid  53885 May 23 08:29 tags.xml
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid   4817 May 23 08:29 templaterc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 mchid mchid    306 May 23 08:28 themerc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 tool-options
drwxr-xr-x 2 mchid mchid   4096 May 23 08:28 tool-presets
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid   3996 May 23 08:29 toolrc
-rw------- 1 mchid mchid   1178 May 23 08:29 unitrc`

Thank you in advance.

---

I have no idea why but all of the options from the unity panel menu are greyed (unless sudo) out but the same options are available by right-clicking on the image.

Comment: Try running `sudo chmod 755 ~/.gimp-2.8`...

Comment: Good idea but I've tried 755 and even 777 with no luck. thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions on the photo you are trying to modify? (Just to check the obvious...)

Comment: Yeah, it's all my photos and even those copied and pasted from the internet (firefox). I found a way to get the options by right-clicking the photo.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al | grep gimp`? You might try deleting the `.gimp` (or `.gimp-2.8` as it is) and then purging gimp and reinstalling it.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  24 mchid mchid      4096 May 24 16:21 .gimp-2.8

Comment: Maybe I should delete the question because other applications have the same problem, not just gimp.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to `chown` the .gimp directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .gimp
```

Try not to run programs as root. If you do, and change settings, the whole settings directory gets owned by root.

Comment: I tried that and no go. I've even purged and reinstalled gimp without luck. thanks

Comment: Odd. Perhaps you can add the output of `ls -l .gimp` to the question. Note, reinstalling gimp doesn't re-write the home folder dirs.

Comment: Perhaps it's the permissions on the photo file(s) themselves rather than the gimp config files - for example if they are on a non-Linux filesystem?

Comment: here's the output

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you executed Gimp as su . And it created .gimp directories  in your home folder . Try  changing ownership of directories to your user

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work and didn't run sudo until after the issue - thanks anyway.